# .Net 4.7 backward compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, backwards-compatibility

I have an application that is built with .Net 4.5.2 as target framework. Can this work seamlessly on a system where only .Net 4.7 is installed? Is there some statement from Microsoft about backward compatibility of the .Net frameworks?

Comment: yes there wont be any issues

Comment: The individual changes between framework versions are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.5.2-4.7). In general things will work without change, but in rare cases you may need to add a configuration setting or otherwise be aware of something that might be a breaking change for your application specifically.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can application with 4.6.2 and server with framework 4.7 work?