# Is .NET 4.6.2 compatible with .NET 4.7?

Tags: .net

On my VM I have .NET 4.6.2 installed and I have a .net website compiled using .NET 4.6.2

I have a new VM with **.NET 4.7 installed**. Is .NET 4.6.2 compatible with .NET 4.7?

1. Can I compile the same .net website code using .NET 4.6.2?
2. On an IIS server that has got .NET 4.7 installed, can I run the .net website with .NET 4.6.2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167382/net-4-7-backward-compatibility#comment98961401_56167382

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes to both your questions.

Slightly longer answer: .NET 4 is an in-place upgrade which means that each upgrade overwrites the previous version in the same file location so that there is only ever one version installed. If you had .NET 4.7 framework installed on your server then your code will work regardless if it targets 4.5 or 4.6.2 or 4.7.

Note: I would install .NET 4.8 as that is the last, most up to date version.

Comment: So install .NET 4.8 on the machine, but use the .NET 4.6.2 in the web config setting?

Comment: yep, should be fine.

Comment: I just installed ASP.NET 4.7 via the server manager and I notice that it has automatically installed the 4.8.3761 version. How do I target the website to use v4.6.2 on such a machine?